# Why can I not deploy to a sandbox without test coverage?

Tags: sandbox, deployment

I have a directory of apex classes, checked into version control, that I need to be able to programatically delete and then re-deploy into a Salesforce Sandbox. I do not want to deploy to production, I just need a quick way to delete all of these files.

So I tried to use the force.com deploy tool to deploy the sample code to my SANDBOX, and it won't let me because of code coverage. Why is this? Is the deploy tool trying to ALSO deploy to production? Why would it do that? Is the deploy tool not meant to be able to deploy local files to a sandbox environment?

EDIT: I have verified that my login credentials are valid by executing ant describeMetadata successfully. Also, my serverurl is set to https://test.salesforce.com

EDIT 2: I commented out the following line from the deployCode target in the sample build.xml
`<runTest>SampleDeployClass</runTest>`

And the deploy worked! Why though? Why would that for some reason affect whether code coverage matters for the rest of the classes in the sandbox?

Comment: Deploying to a sandbox should work without test code coverage. I would encourage you to check your login credentials again.

Comment: I have set my sf.serverurl to https://test.salesforce.com, and I am able to successfully execute ant describeMetadata

Comment: Also, I have set runAllTests to "false" in the sample build.xml file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the tests are run they are not only run - but also their results will be taken into account. That means a rollback on failure.  Not meeting the test coverage counts as failure and you get your rollback.

Not running the tests as you set it up now brings you another advantage: you could save a lot of time, since tests may slow down the deployment significantly.

But if you want the tests for some reason to be run I would recommend to do it separately after deployment in the background. Either manually or automated but decoupled from this process.

Comment: Do you have any documentation of that behavior? I suppose it makes sense, but it would be really nice if Salesforce specified these things instead of the whole thing being guesswork.

Comment: I have no documentation but if you find something let all of us know.

Comment: This seems to be the official docu http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_deploy_running_tests.htm (still room for interpretation) and here others talk about similar experiences https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008veIIAQ

Comment: And there seems to be another parameter rollbackOnError according to this  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_deploy.htm

Answer (score 1):

Usually for sandbox deployment, salesforce doesn't run all tests. It may be because the deployment tool, is trying to run all tests. But I'm sure salesfore doesn't run all tests in sandboxes :)

Answer (score 0):

Quick addition to this, if you're deploying to a sandbox, don't run any specified test, just leave it to default and it won't require coverage to deploy.

If you run a specified test, then the default requirement of 75% coverage becomes active again